# Redefine \captionbelow as \caption

Tags: macros, captions

**Background:** I *must* produce a `.docx` version of my `.tex` document. I use `pandoc` for that. 
My document uses a KOMA class, and thus use `\captionbelow`. However, `pandoc` does not handle the latter: it produce a caption in the `.docx` document only when one uses `\caption`. I thus want to 'change' `\captionbelow` definition, so that `pandoc` acts as if it were `\caption`.

For that, I want to redefine `\captionbelow` at the beginning of my document, so that my document content remains untouched. However, I tried both of following commands, but it makes compilation never stops:

```
\renewcommand{\captionbelow}{\caption}
\renewcommand{\captionbelow}[2][]{\caption[#1]{#2}}
```

**Question:** How to redefine `\captionbelow` as `\caption`?

(It seems a really easy question but cannot figure out how to do!)

Comment: True, I was thinking in the wrong direction. Type `\meaning\captionbelow` in the document body (without trying to redefine it) and see how the macro is defined

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hmm, it says `\captionbelow=\long macro:
->\@captionabovefalse \scr@caption .` but I'm not sure what to do with this information...

Comment: In KOMA-script you can use `\caption{}` instead of `\captionbelow{}`. It behaves the same if you did not use the `captions=` key in the KOMAoptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In KOMA-script the `\caption` command can be adjusted using the `captions=<option>` key either in `\KOMAoptions` or as argument to the documentclass, etc. Therefore you do not have to use `\captionbelow` or `\captionabove` at all.

If you want to let `\caption` always behave like `\captionbelow` don't use the `captions` key at all as this is the default or use `captions=signature`.

If you want `\caption` to behave like `\captionabove` only in `table`-environments use `captions=tableheading`.

If you want `\caption` to behave like `\captionabove` only in `figure`-environments use `captions=figureheading`.

If you want `\caption` to always behave like `\captionabove` you can use `captions=heading`.

For the `figure` and `table` arguments you can also set `captions=figuresignature` or `captions=tablesignature`.

With this you shouldn't need to use `\captionabove` or `\captionbelow` at all.

Note that you can change the behavior of `\caption` midway through your document using `\KOMAoptions{captions=<option>}`. Also note that this is what `\captionbelow` and `\captionabove` actually do. They locally change the behavior to `heading` and `signature`, respectively, and invoke the `caption`-command `\scr@caption`.

Comment: Using `\KOMAoption{captions}{figuresignature,tableheading}`, and replacing both `\captionbelow` and `\captionabove` with `\caption` indeed solved the problem. *(Caution, I'm using the syntax `\KOMAoption{foo}{bar,baz}` and not `\KOMAoptions{foo=bar,foo=baz}` - with an* s *at the end - here!)*

Comment: @ebo good to know. But the results of your command should be the same as `\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}` because the `figuresignature` is the default and is not touched by `tableheading`. And it doesn't really matter whether you use `\KOMAoptions` or `\KOMAoption`, that's more a matter of taste.

Comment: you're right. my comment was only intended to drop a "ready-to-go takeaway". (I was not sure about `figuresignature` being default - the KOMA documentation is not fully explicit about this). Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @ebo and my answer was trying to be as versatile as possible while still providing all information to answer your question (though I was not sure, what you wanted to be `below` and what `above`).